# PyGithub: how to search for multiple topics using get_repositories

Tags: python, github, pygithub

Using PyGithub, I'm trying to search for github repositories using multiple topics.

This works for one topic:

```
Github.search_repositories("topic:topicname1")
```

But how do I add others? I've tried "topic:topicname1+topic:topicname2" but that doesn't seem to work. Adding multiple topic arguments also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There was one stupidly obvious thing I forgot to try, and it works! Just put a space in between each topic.

```
Github.search_repositories("topic:topicname1 topic:topicname2")
```